# PHP fsockopen() cookies

Tags: php, cookies, fsockopen

I'm trying to create a 'remote login' site, but when I try the below code, I get the error about cookies being disabled, I've googled for a solution, but the only solved case has cURL way of doing that(cookie jar), how could I solve the cookie problem? And how could I find the cookie that the site needs(it has about 10 of them)?

```
<?php
$vars = array(
    'email' => "*****",
    'pass'=>"*****"
    );
$content = http_build_query($vars);

$host = 'www.site.com';
$service_uri = '/login.php';
$vars ='login_mode=1';

$header = "Host: $host\r\n";
$header .= "User-Agent: PHP Script\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Referer: http://www.site.com \r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($content)."\r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

$fp = fsockopen("".$host,80, $errno, $errstr);

if (!$fp)
{
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br/>\n";
    echo $fp;
}
else
{
    fputs($fp, "POST $service_uri  HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    fputs($fp, $header.$content);

    while(!feof($fp))
    {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: dynamic, that's not true at all. It's easy to read the HTTP headers yourself and handle the cookies manually.

Comment: Was going to say you could parse the "Set-Cookie:" headers in.

Comment: yes,I've seen the Set-Cookie, but I don't know which cookie it is...

Comment: How should we know which cookie it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first have to request the homepage URL, which will give you cookie headers. Parse them and send them to the server by adding them to your `$header` variable.

You don't want to care about which cookie the site needs - just send all of them, which makes it future-proof.

If you don't want to do that all yourself, have a look at PEAR's [HTTP_Request2](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2) package - it has cookie handling built-in.